# Create text file to read from every day

Tags: php, text-files

What I'm attempting to do is create a simple "Quote of the Day" script. What this needs to do is be able to read from a simple .txt file, grab each entry per line and output the contents of that line, once per day. For example, if a .txt file had the following text:

```
This is the quote of the day
This is another quote of the day
This is the last quote of the day
```

Then, the script would grab the first block of text, `This is the quote of the day` and output it on the site. It would then cycle through, line by line, based on each incremental day until the end (and then cycle back to the beginning). Hopefully this would just allow people to cut/paste new info in as it would rely on line numbers, not the content itself.

If anyone even knows of a .XML implementation of this - it would be a big help - trying to figure out the simplest way of going about this. Thanks!

Comment: -1 What did you try? what didn't work? We won't do the work for you

Comment: I've done research on if CRON would be the way to go and how to read files using PHP - not looking for the work to be done - asking if anyone has seen an implementation that I could look at for further reference (don't appreciate the negative tick).

Comment: The idea isn't that you should appreciate negative votes. The idea is that you should rethink the way you post qustions. Ask more specific questions, what you tried and what failed. Usually we want people to try before posting

Comment: I completely understand, just didn't appreciate assuming I wanted the work done for me. I'm new to Stack Overflow, but understand that it's a community for helping people. Helping doesn't mean doing the work for them, it means helping them understand what they are after to get what they need done and in this case, to also help others that may come across a similar situation. I do appreciate the advice to form my questions a bit more specific though - as I can see how that would help everyone a bit more. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry if I was harsh, but it did not seem as though you had tried as you did not mention it on your question

Comment: Hi @Oskar - no reason to apologize, just something for me to learn for the future. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you had a file with 365 lines (one line per the current day)...

```
$lines = file("quotes.txt");
$day = date("z");
echo $lines[$day];
```

Comment: Maybe you want to make that 366 to cover off leap years?

Comment: Hi - Thanks - I'll start digging into this - it might be the way to go. I'll let you know. Thanks again!

Comment: All awesome answered provided here (was completely missing using date()), this one seemed to fit the bill. Here is what I ended up with:

    `<?php
    $quotes = file('quotes.txt');
    $the_quote = $quotes[ date('j')-1 ];
    echo $the_quote;
    ?>`

Thanks for everyone's help!

Answer (score 0):

It's very simple.

#### 1.) You create a text file with 7 lines, each line represents a quote.

#### 2.) PHP: You have to load the file into an array and get the numeric representation of the current day of the week:

```
$quotes = file('your_file.txt');

$the_quote = $quotes[ date('w') ];

echo $the_quote;
```

From [`php.net`](http://php.net/manual/function.date.php):

```
w
Numeric representation of the day of the week
0 (for Sunday) through 6 (for Saturday)
```

If you want to have a quote for each day *in a year*, just create a file with 366 lines and use `date('z')`.

Answer (score 0):

You can save the current index line and day on the first line of the file, like this:

```
01;09-11-2011
This is the quote of the day
This is another quote of the day
This is the last quote of the day
```

To retrieve the quote you would check if the date is today, if it is you get the nth line otherwise you add 1 to the number, update the date and then get the quote.

Answer (score 0):

This should work with any number of lines in your textfile (untested):

```
// get lines
$lines = file('lines.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES );

// snap to midnight
$day = mktime(0,0,0, date("n"), date("j"), date("Y")) / (3600*24);

// modulo fun
echo $lines[ $day % count($lines) ];
```

Answer (score 0):

The most flexible way is definitely:

```
$day = date("z");
$file = file('quotes.txt');
$file_length = count($file);

$quote = $file[$day % file_length];
```

By using the modulus of the day and file length you have a recurring cycle every day from the first line to the last line of the file (and then start again).